# Is this number an algebraic integer over $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

> Let $$\alpha=(\sqrt[713]{5}+\sqrt{2}+i)\sqrt[13]{100001}.$$
>   Is this number an algebraic integer over $\mathbb{Z}$?

I have really no clue,  because I do not find any polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ which has $\alpha$ as a root. Maybe I have to consider the norm, but this does not bring me further.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course it is hard to find such a polynomial. But it is well known that the algebraic integers form a ring, they are closed under addition and multiplication. It is not hard to check that the four constants which appear in the definition of $\alpha$ are indeed algebraic integers, so $\alpha$ is an algebraic integer as well.

Comment: Does "over $ \mathbb{Z}$" mean that the coefficients have to be in $\mathbb{Z}$? For example for the first term I have the polynomial $x^{713}-5$

Comment: It has to be a monic polynomial (it is important that it's monic) with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$. Yes, you got the first one right. The others are similar.

Comment: Thanks for your help .